# manjaro can't set system proxy

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, proxy

I downloaded and installed manjaro-kde six hours ago, and before that I used ubuntu-gnome.

I found that marjaro cannot set a global system proxy, but this works fine on ubuntu.

I found some information, but I don't know what to do next.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Proxy_settings

```
Proxy settings

NetworkManager does not directly handle proxy settings, but if you are using GNOME or KDE, you could use proxydriver which handles proxy settings using NetworkManager's information. proxydriver is found in the package proxydriverAUR.

In order for proxydriver to be able to change the proxy settings, you would need to execute this command, as part of the GNOME startup process (see GNOME#Autostart).

xhost +si:localuser:username

See also Proxy settings
```

Is there any way to make my proxy take effect global? I miss the smooth use of global proxies on ubuntu.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you installed the proper packages? Have you followed the steps mentioned in the Arch wiki that you posted? If so, what happens? We need more info.